# Subquery in Snowflake select clause not evaluating row by row?

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write a very straightforward query: I want to pull all accounts in a snowflake table, and flag accounts (True/False) that can be linked to a record in the opportunity table with "Startup" in the type field.

Here is a query that I thought would return what I am looking for:

```
SELECT
    acc.id
    , acc.id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT(opp.accountid)
        FROM "OPPORTUNITY" opp
        WHERE opp.type LIKE '%Startup%'
        ) AS startup
FROM "ACCOUNT" acc
```

The account table has ~100,000 distinct records and the subquery returns a list of only ~11,000 distinct account ids, yet the field aliased as 'startup' contains TRUE for each account. I've tried diagnosing why this returns all True with no luck. I also tried writing this same query using EXISTS with a correlated subquery and got the same results.

I was able to build a working query by essentially left joining the sub query after the FROM clause, but I would love to understand why the query above fails to evaluate correctly for each row.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you see:

```
create or replace table ACCOUNT(id int);
insert into ACCOUNT values (1), (2), (3);
create or replace table OPPORTUNITY(accountid int, type varchar);
insert into OPPORTUNITY values (1, 'Startup'), (2, 'Startup');
```

Running your query above then produces the result:

```
Row   ID   STARTUP
1     1    TRUE
2     2    TRUE
3     3    FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Weird right? I've used almost identical logic in other queries and never had an issue before. I've had several coworkers take a look at this issue and it has stumped everyone. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

it'd be interesting for us to see the results of these two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT accountid)
FROM   opportunity
WHERE  type LIKE '%Startup%';


SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT accountid)
FROM   opportunity
WHERE  type iLike '%Startup%';
```

Something like the following might be your ultimate goal I think:

```
SELECT acc.id,
       startup.accountid
FROM   ACCOUNT acc
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT accountid) as accountid
    FROM   opportunity
    WHERE  type iLike '%Startup%'
    AND    accountid IS NOT NULL) startup 
ON acc.id = startup.accountid;
```

**** **begin additional info** ****

After reading the comments, I decided to play with this a little more, sure enough my test is working, perhaps you have nulls or similar messing up your data or results?  I'm not sure but this is working for me!

```
create table account (id varchar);
insert into account values ('A'), ('B'),('C'),('D');

create table opportunity (accountid varchar, type varchar);
insert into opportunity values ('D', 'New Subscription'), ('X', 'Stuff'), ('Y', 'Stuff'), ('Z', 'Stuff');

select account.id,
       account.id in (select distinct accountid FROM opportunity WHERE type like '%Subscr%') as startup
FROM   account;

ID  STARTUP
A   FALSE
B   FALSE
C   FALSE
D   TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The two queries above both returned the same amount (~11k). And thanks for the second query with the left join. It does work as intended (and I'll use that as a solution for now), but I'd still love to figure out what might be going wrong in the original query - any other ideas?

Comment: Can you share a small set (2-3 rows) of example values from OPPORTUNITY and ACCOUNT that deliver "TRUE" for the IN test where they should deliver false?  I would like to try to create a tiny reproduceable set reflecting actual values from the tables...

Comment: Hey Stuart, definitely. Here's a small subset of the data I'm querying: 


ACCOUNT
{id: 'A'}
{id: 'B'}
{id: 'C'}
{id: 'D'}


OPPORTUNITY
{accountid: 'A', type: 'New Subscription'}
{accountid: 'B', type: 'New Subscription - Startup'}
{accountid: 'D', type: 'New Subscription'}

The query in my original post returns TRUE for all accounts, but I'm trying to only flag Account 'B' as TRUE

Comment: I get the same bad result when the ACCOUNT and OPPORTUNITY tables use VARIANT type, but not when using fully-structured columns -- so a bug I'll report.

Comment: Interesting, all values (acc.id, opp.account, opp.type) in the tables are stored as VARCHARs. You're saying that you had success with fully structured columns?

Comment: I added an actual example above, I hope it helps!